# need confirmation or needs confirmation

Tags: verbs, american-english, north-american-english

I receive an issue reported in an issue tracker. That issue requires confirmation to check if it is a real issue.

How should the label be names as:

`Need confirmation` or `Needs confirmation`?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Is whatever needs confirmation singular or plural? If "an issue" is the subject, then use "needs"; if "issues" is the subject, then use "need". Examples: An issue *needs* confirmation. These issues *need* confirmation.

Or, if you are referring to a person, then use the appropriate singular/plural form of need. Examples: I *need* confirmation. We *need* confirmation. They *need* confirmation. She *needs* confirmation.

Even if there will be no subject in front of your "need/needs confirmation" label when it's presented to others, the subject should determine if it is "need" or "needs."

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you view the thought behind the message. It could be "I/We **need** confirmation or "This **needs** conformation".

Comment: What is the core difference between the two? In this context if I am saying this needs confirmation would it be different than "I need confirmation"? If there is no difference between the two, is it safe to assume both are correct?

Answer (score 0):

Although either label may be correct in isolation, in the context of an issue tracker I think it is more appropriate to use "needs confirmation".

It is the issue that is the focus of attention. As well as "needs confirmation" there will probably be other labels such as "In progress", "In Quality Assurance" or "Resolved".

All labels should operate in the same way .  You don't want to mix "We need confirmation" with "This issue is in progress" or "This issue is resolved".